# IONIC-ANGULAR Problema com: You must include credentials to use this auth method

Tags: ionic, typescript, angular

Olá,
Após implementar o método de Login para minha aplicação e tentar fazer o login, um erro acaba aparecendo: "You must include credentials to use this auth method". 
Já procurei em vários lugares, mas não tive respostas que acabassem resolvendo meu problema!

Método de (onSubmit)
[image: método de para realizar login]

Minha provider de auth.ts:
[image: authService]

Estou sem entender do porquê dele não está reconhecendo minhas credenciais, pois estou com meu firebase configurado:

Método de login E-mail/Senha - Ativado

Usuários de autenticação - Existe

Existe algo de errado que eu não consegui observar?

Desde já, Obrigado!

Comment: Verificou se as credencias estão sendo passadas corretamente e chegando até o método de autenticação?

Comment: Sim, inclusive coloquei para apresentar um log para saber se as credenciais estão sendo capturadas e do mesmo jeito o erro continua.